# Problem woth my 03 Subaru Forester 2.5

Tags: subaru, forester, fuel-pressure-regulator

So I replaced the motor and when I first did it. It was running good and then all hell broke loose start running really bad and the more I got liking into this problem I remember I broke something when putting my new motor in wasn't sure what it was but it was the fuel pressure regulator I didn't have hook up it run good for 943 miles if this is the problem did I mess up my motor or after I fix this will it run right again or what am I gonna have to do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I understand you are having a problem and you're frustrated, however, as it is written, I really don't understand what your problem might be. Could you edit your question and add some details? Is there a check engine light on? If so, have you read those and if so, what are they? How is it running bad? What does "all hell broke loose" mean? Could you explain what you did with your fuel pressure regulator which might have caused issues? We need some help here so we can help you.

Comment: Whether you know it or not, a fuel pressure regulator sets fuel pressure so the EFI system can run the engine. Without a set pressure, the engine can run lean, correct, rich, all the time, creating; emissions problems, excess fuel in oil,  melted pistons, burned valves, damaged spark plugs, damaged catalytic converters, etc. Replace the fuel pressure regulator and see what happens next. Removing sparks plugs may give you a hint of how the engine runs. Spark plug condition charts can help determine engine running issues.